# DGLError when running GCN for image classification with DGL and PyTorch

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am working on an image classification task using Graph Convolutional Networks (GCN) with Deep Graph Library (DGL) and PyTorch. i am using Google Collab and have defined a GCN model for the task and implemented a custom dataset to load and process the images. However, I encountered an error when training the model.

The error occurs when trying to move the batched graphs to the device using the to(device) method. Specifically, I get the following error:

> DGLError: [05:34:44] /opt/dgl/src/runtime/c_runtime_api.cc:82: Check
> failed: allow_missing: Device API cuda is not enabled. Please install
> the cuda version of dgl.

I have checked that my device is set to GPU (device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')) and have installed the necessary dependencies. However, I'm still facing this error.
My full code:

```
import os
import cv2
import torch
import dgl
import networkx as nx
from torchvision.datasets import VisionDataset
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Define the GCN model
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from dgl.nn import GraphConv

class GCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feats, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(GCN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GraphConv(in_feats, hidden_size)
        self.conv2 = GraphConv(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, g, features):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(g, features))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(g, x))
        x = dgl.mean_nodes(g, x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x


class CustomImageDataset(VisionDataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None):
        super(CustomImageDataset, self).__init__(root, transform=transform)
        self.image_paths = self._load_image_paths()
        self.class_map = self._create_class_map()

    def _load_image_paths(self):
        image_paths = []
        for class_name in os.listdir(self.root):
            class_path = os.path.join(self.root, class_name)
            if os.path.isdir(class_path):
                image_paths.extend([os.path.join(class_path, file) for file in os.listdir(class_path)])
        return image_paths

    def _create_class_map(self):
        classes = sorted(set([os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)) for path in self.image_paths]))
        class_map = {class_name: i for i, class_name in enumerate(classes)}
        return class_map

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.image_paths[index]
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')  # Open as grayscale image
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        class_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(image_path))
        label = self.class_map[class_name]
        return image, label

def collate(samples):
    graphs, labels = map(list, zip(*samples))
    batched_graph = dgl.batch(graphs)
    return batched_graph, torch.tensor(labels)

# Set the root directory of your custom image dataset
root_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Brain Tumor Image Dataset Splitted/data'

# Set the desired transformation (if any)
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

# Create an instance of the custom image dataset
custom_dataset = CustomImageDataset(root_dir, transform=transform)

akaze = cv2.AKAZE_create()
graphs = []
labels = []
for image, label in custom_dataset:
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension
    image_np = image.squeeze().numpy()  # Convert image tensor to NumPy array
    kp, des = akaze.detectAndCompute(image_np, None)
    if len(kp) == 0:
        continue

    top_des = torch.tensor(des, dtype=torch.float32)
    g = dgl.from_networkx(nx.complete_graph(top_des.shape[0]))
    g.ndata['feat'] = top_des

    graphs.append(g)
    labels.append(label)

# Save the graph datasets
output_labels = {'label': torch.tensor(labels)}
graph_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/graphs.dgl'
dgl.save_graphs(graph_file, g_list=graphs, labels=output_labels)

# Load the saved graph datasets
loaded_graphs, loaded_labels = dgl.load_graphs(graph_file)
train_graphs = loaded_graphs
train_labels = loaded_labels['label']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_graphs, test_graphs, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(train_graphs, train_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the GCN model
input_size = train_graphs[0].ndata['feat'].shape[1]
hidden_size = 64
num_classes = len(custom_dataset.class_map)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = GCN(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes).to(device)

# Set up the training parameters
num_epochs = 50
batch_size = 32
learning_rate = 0.001
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Create DataLoader for batch processing with the custom collate function
train_data = list(zip(train_graphs, train_labels))
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate)

# Training loop
model.train()
```

Here is the relevant part of my code where the error occurs:
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
epoch_loss = 0
for batch_graphs, batch_labels in train_loader:
batch_graphs = batch_graphs.to(device)
batch_labels = batch_labels.to(device)

```
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        batch_features = batch_graphs.ndata['feat']
        batch_output = model(batch_graphs, batch_features)

        loss = criterion(batch_output, batch_labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += loss.item() * batch_labels.size(0)

    epoch_loss /= len(train_graphs)
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}')

# Evaluation on the testing set
model.eval()
test_data = list(zip(test_graphs, test_labels))
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, collate_fn=collate)

total_correct = 0
total_samples = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch_graphs, batch_labels in test_loader:
        batch_graphs = batch_graphs.to(device)
        batch_labels = batch_labels.to(device)

        batch_features = batch_graphs.ndata['feat']
        batch_output = model(batch_graphs, batch_features)
        _, predicted_labels = torch.max(batch_output, dim=1)

        total_correct += (predicted_labels == batch_labels).sum().item()
        total_samples += batch_labels.size(0)

accuracy = total_correct / total_samples
print(f'Testing Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!